# How show only two decimals from a function

Tags: javascript, xml, odoo-12

I have a function that give me a quantity from a product but it displays 3 decimals and I want to show only two

```
<t t-esc="orderline.get_quantity_str_with_unit()" />
```

I tried this:

```
<t t-esc="orderline.get_quantity_str_with_unit().toFixed(2)"/>
```

Comment: What does `orderline.get_quantity_str_with_unit()` return? The function name suggests it returns a string containing a number and a unit. You can't call `toFixed` on a string.

Comment: Try with `parseInt(orderline.get_quantity_str_with_unit()).toFixed(2)`

Answer (score -2):

I am assuming your function returns a string. You were not very clear with what your function returns, but try this:

```
Number(yourFunction()).toFixed(2)
```